# ajax can i use ajax to send a variable which is use in mysql perform some query then result back to me as return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

this is my code for in php file from which i recall a refresh php again nd again its working fine but now i have $id which i get while performing some query now i want to send it refresh.php page where some query will be performed then i get result back as return

```
function repeatAjax(){
var arrPoints;
$.ajax({
    url: 'refresh.php',
   cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      if(result){  

      var resultJson = $.parseJSON(result);

refresh_point(resultJson["latitude"],resultJson["longitude"]);
 }
 }
}); }
```

this is my refresh.php page

```
<?php 


$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="map";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);



//i want $id here so i can use it instead of 6 

    $query_search1 = "SELECT lat ,lng FROM van WHERE id =6";

    $query_exec2 = mysql_query($query_search1) or die(mysql_error());


    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec2);  
    $row1= $row['lat'];
    $row2= $row['lng'];
 $advert = array(
        'latitude' => $row['lat'],
        'longitude' => $row['lng'],
     );
    echo json_encode($advert);



?>
```

code is working awesome if i don't want to send some thing to refresh php if i just type id 6 i get the return OK fine but i want to post some thing but how ??

Comment: can u brief more.. not able to understand

Comment: yes you can send variable in ajax request under "data" param

Comment: also from where you get $id  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function repeatAjax(){
    var arrPoints;
 var id = '6';
    $.ajax({
            url: 'refresh.php',
        data: id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if(result){  

            var resultJson = $.parseJSON(result);

        refresh_point(resultJson["latitude"],resultJson["longitude"]);
         }
         }
    });
}



    In php file you can recive vairable like below

    $id=$_POST['id'];
```

Comment: got you but i did it   var jsonString = JSON.stringify(<?php echo $id;?>); ......    data: {data: jsonString},  in ajax it work like charm but this approach is good or not ???